# Apply two numpy functions at the same time for aggfunc when using pivot_table

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have this table:

```
user_id | datetime   | type
1       | 2015-01-01 | 1
1       | 2015-01-01 | 2
1       | 2015-01-01 | 2
1       | 2015-01-02 | 2
2       | 2015-01-01 | 2
2       | 2015-01-02 | 1
2       | 2015-01-02 | 2
```

I have this `pivot_table` code:

```
df = df.pivot_table('type', ['user_id'], ['datetime'], aggfunc=np.mean)
```

However, instead of `np.mean` I want to apply both unique().sum() functions together to meet this condition:

> If there are both `1` and `2` during specific days per user, then I
>   want to put `3`, if there is only `1` for a specific day I want to put
>   `2`, etc.

For example here is the desired output as follows:

```
user_id | 2015-01-01 | 2015-01-02 
1       | 3          | 2 
2       | 2          | 3
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
In [50]: df.pivot_table('type', ['user_id'], ['datetime'], aggfunc=lambda x: x.unique().sum())
Out[50]:
datetime  2015-01-01  2015-01-02
user_id
1                  3           2
2                  2           3
```

Comment: I tried it within `{}`, that is why it was not working... Thanks again :)